# socket.io for react native (sending query problems)

Tags: sockets, react-native, socket.io, serversocket

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/kirkness/react-native-swift-socketio) and i can connect without problems.

Usually when I have worked with sockets the code that ever i used is:

`socket = io.connect(url, { query: ‘token=’ + token});`

and i can see this info reading `socket.request._query`

> Using [socket.io for react native](https://github.com/kirkness/react-native-swift-socketio) i'm trying to send params:
>
> `this.socket = new SocketIO('http://localhost:3000', { query: ‘token=’ + token});`

but in `socket.request._query` only can see this log:

`{ transport: 'polling', b64: '1' }`

In the library some options are mentioned like: `connectParams`. But i don't know how i can see the info

**Related**: [link](https://github.com/gcrabtree/react-native-socketio/issues/18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty detailed in the repo, but `connectParams` is a key/value object, and furthermore the values you sent in it will be appended in the url, as shown here:

```
    if connectParams != nil {
        for (key, value) in connectParams! {
            let keyEsc   = key.urlEncode()!
            let valueEsc = "\(value)".urlEncode()!

            queryString += "&\(keyEsc)=\(valueEsc)"
        }
    }
```

[>Source<](https://github.com/gcrabtree/react-native-socketio/blob/2c89dc9eebca8adca44211df01db650ad6e4ad04/ios/RNSwiftSocketIO/SocketIOClient/SocketEngine.swift#L226)

So, you should try using `connectParams` like this(though I'm not sure how you tried it before):

```
this.socket = new SocketIO('http://localhost:3000', {
  connectParams: {
    myAwesomeQueryStringParam: "someRandomValue"
  }
});
```

PS: forgive me, my english is pretty bad